# Printscreen no Selenium com popup

Tags: testes, firefox

Gostaria de saber se é possível tirar um **printscreen** da tela com um *popup* de alerta, por exemplo, no **Selenium IDE**.

A função `captureEntirePageScreenshot` faz o Printscreen, porém, somente do browser e não com o popup junto.

Alguém saberia como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Vinicius,
Se tu estás falando de um alerta Javascript, como [estes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp), tu não conseguirá tirar um printscreen porque o Selenium IDE não faz uma ação direta de clique em alertas, confirmações e prompts em Javascript.

Nesta [página da documentação oficial do Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows), temos o seguinte trecho:

> When running under Selenium, JavaScript pop-ups will not appear. This is because the function calls are actually being overridden at runtime by Selenium’s own JavaScript...

Traduzindo...

> Quando executado via Selenium, popups Javascript não aparecerão. Isto ocorre porque as funções de chamada são sobrescritas em tempo de execução pelo próprio Javascript do Selenium...

Logo, qualquer tentativa de fazer com que este tipo de popup aparece em uma screenshot com Selenium IDE vai falhar (não vai aparecer).